# How to visit All URL's Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to visit all the displayed urls but it visit first not all

Google search URL https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Rashmi+Custom+Tailors

```
    browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Rashmi+Custom+Tailors')
    time.sleep(5)

    try:        
        p_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(' div > h3 > a')
        url_list = []
        for urls in p_links:
            if "Rashmi Custom Tailors" in urls.text:

                url = urls.get_attribute("href")
                url_list.append(url)
                for url in url_list:
                    browser.get(url)
                    time.sleep(4)

    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the result of your **bad practice** by using:

```
try:
   do something
except:
    pass
```

With this block of line, you cannot catch any infomation about why the program did run as you expected. **The exception it throws help you improve your code, don't ingore it like this.**

Now, back to your question. In your code, there are some logic error like [@Mohammad Rakib Amin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43400417/6597344). So, make a little change to your code, you got this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = selenium.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Rashmi+Custom+Tailors')
time.sleep(5)
p_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(' div > h3 > a')
for urls in p_links:
    if "Rashmi Custom Tailors" in urls.text:
        url = urls.get_attribute("href")
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(4)
```

But this did not solve your problem, your browser will only visit this first url 
 like you described and raise an Exception:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This Exception is throw because during the second loop, the element your are using are no longer attached to browser's current page.

A solution to this is just like what your did, find all elements and append all the urls to a list. And you iterate the list like this one, and it run well on my computer. Try it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
query_url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Rashmi+Custom+Tailors"
browser.get(query_url)
p_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > h3 > a")
urls = []
for elem in p_links:
    text = elem.text
    url = elem.get_property('href')
    if "Rashmi Custom Tailors" in elem.text:
        urls.append(url)

for url in urls:
    browser.get(url)
```

Perhaps you made some `indent error` in your second loop.

P.S: You question should contain all the code needed, it makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two loops for no reason. Try this:

```
        p_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(' div > h3 > a') 
        for urls in p_links: // All the urls in first page
           if "Rashmi Custom Tailors" in urls.text: 
              url = urls.get_attribute("href") // the first match
              browser.get(url) // goto first match
              time.sleep(4)
```

Then navigate to second page using a counter to compare, something like:

```
if counter == len(p_link): 
   // click this_page + 1 etc.
```