# How to Visit all URL's in the search Results using Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Here is my Code it just visit first URL not all.. please let me know how to fix that..

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile 
import random 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

browser.get('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Mobiles+in+london')
time.sleep(5)

try:        
        p_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(' div > h3 > a')
        url_list = []
        for urls in p_links:
            if "London" in urls.text:

                urls.get_attribute("href")
                url_list.append(urls)
                for links in url_list:
                    browser.get(links)
                    time.sleep(4)
except:
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372972/how-to-visit-all-urls-selenium-python  why post this question again with a different user?

Comment: cuz I didn't receive any answer but sorry about that that question was posted my my partner

Comment: is ther any solution

Answer (score 1):

Here you are adding web element to the url_list instead of href attribute value so its throwing exception when it is hitting the line driver.get(webelement)

Below is the modified code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rashmi&oq=Rashmi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.6857j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=Mobiles+in+london')
time.sleep(5)

try:        
        p_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > h3 > a')
        url_list = []
        for url in p_links:
            print url.get_attribute("href")
            url_list.append(url.get_attribute("href"))
        for urls in url_list:
            if "london" in urls:
                print "Opening "+urls
                driver.get(urls)
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
    driver.close()

driver.close()
```

Let me know if it works for you.